# Azure DevOps API to query Work item title based on a specific text

Tags: azure-devops

How can use ADO Rest API to query ADO work item based on Title of a work item?

I check the API doc, but I don't see a way where I can use a work item title based a given string.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/search/work%20item%20search%20results/fetch%20work%20item%20search%20results?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#uri-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST API [Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1).

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=6.1-preview.2
```

Here is an example of the request body:

```
{
  "query": "Select [System.Id] From WorkItems Where [System.Title] CONTAINS '{your specific test}'"
}
```